# "Invisible label" to add to tree

Tags: sectioning, captions, winedt

Is there a way to create a subsection, without caption but add a reference to it in the WinEdt Tree?

I am talking about WinEdt 9.

Comment: Hi and welcome, subsection, caption and tree are three words with completely different meaning. I am not quite sure what you mean. Do you want to have an extra entry in the table of contents on level 'subsection', without a real subsection on your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

Instead of simply writing

```
\subsection{}
```

add a space as the argument of the `\subsection`:

```
\subsection{ }
```

From a TeX point of view it changes nothing in your document, but WinEdt is now able to collect that `\subsection` in its Tree interface, since the argument is now non-empty.

With this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{A named section}
Hello!
\subsection{A named subsection}
Hello again!
\subsection{ }
\TeX{} considers this subsection title empty, but WinEdt Tree doesn't\ldots
\subsection{Another named subsection}
Hello again!
\end{document}
```

this is what you will see in WinEdt:

[image]

and this is the document output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but here an aswer
[image]

Here you can do bookmark anywhere in your document, just right clic the bleu arrow.

If you realy need a subsection without any heading (caption) that's mean something just like `\subsection{}` you can do `\subsection{\empty}`

Comment: `\subsection{empty}` will create a header for the subsection. Even `\subsection{}` will insert its number.

Comment: @Sigur thanks i mean `\empty` 'll edit my answer